# display object parameter from inside array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the following code, how can I identify with the scheduleVariableTest parameter? When I console.log this.scheduleSettings it shows my object, I just can't seem to find the correct selector to display the test.

I have tried this.scheduleSettings.scheduleVariableTest, this.scheduleSettings[0].scheduleVariableTest and they all come back undefined. =/

```
    var ReservationSchedulePicker = function(reservationType){
    this.scheduleSettings = []; // Main settings for Schedule Picker
    this.scheduleSettings[''] = { // Default Main Settings for Schedule Picker
        scheduleReservationType : reservationType,
        scheduleVariableTest : "Testing",
        schedulePickerID : $("#schedulePicker"),
        scheduleMarkup : "",
        schedulePickerTotalCostID : $("#schedulePickerTotal"),
        schedulePickerTotalCost : "",
        schedulePickerErrors : [],
        schedulePickerErrorsID : $("#schedulePickerErrors")
    };
```

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Comment: If you define a variable with `var scheduleSettings` inside a function, it's only avaible in this function. If you define it outside the function or without `var` it's everywhere avaible. Look at my answer - I defined it outside, because I do not know where do you want use this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scheduleSettings = {};

var ReservationSchedulePicker = function(reservationType){
     scheduleSettings = { // Default Main Settings for Schedule Picker
        scheduleReservationType : reservationType,
        scheduleVariableTest : "Testing",
        schedulePickerID : $("#schedulePicker"),
        scheduleMarkup : "",
        schedulePickerTotalCostID : $("#schedulePickerTotal"),
        schedulePickerTotalCost : "",
        schedulePickerErrors : [],
        schedulePickerErrorsID : $("#schedulePickerErrors")
     };
};

ReservationSchedulePicker('wohoo');
console.log(scheduleSettings.scheduleReservationType) // output: 'wohoo'
```